# android:launchMode

Tags: android

На сайте [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=ru) про режим запуска (`launchMode`) `"standard"` написано:

> Режим по умолчанию. Система создает новый экземпляр операции в задаче,
>   из которой она была запущена, и направляет ему намерение. Может быть
>   создано несколько экземпляров операции, каждый экземпляр может
>   принадлежать различным задачам, и одна задача может содержать
>   несколько экземпляров.

Но при этом если я добавляю во все `<activity>` приложения (назовём его *myApp*) атрибут

```
android:launchMode="standard"
```

и после запуска приложения (*myApp*) из ActivityA открываю ActivityB обычным `Intent` без флагов:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

открывается окно ActivityB, потом запускаю другое приложение и после этого нажимаю на ярлык первого приложения (*myApp*) на главном экране, открывается уже запущенный экземпляр активности ActivityB, в уже запущенной задаче.  Хотя судя по приведённому описанию в документации должен создаваться новый экземпляр ActivityA, разве нет? Это поведение наблюдается и на эмуляторе (Pixel XL API 26), и на реальном телефоне (версия Android 6.0.1). Почему так происходит?..

**UPD**

И когда я в теге  для ActivityB указала

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

на эмуляторе указанного в документации поведения также не наблюдается - новой задачи для окна ActivityB на экране обзора не создаётся. Однако при запуске на реальном устройстве ActivityB открывается верно, в новой задаче. Но в документации на этой же странице указано следующее:

> И при запуске операции в новой задаче, и при запуске операции в
>   существующей задаче, кнопка Назад всегда возвращает пользователя к
>   предыдущей операции

При этом при тестировании приложения на устройстве после открытия из ActivityB нового окна ActivityС оно открывается в первой задаче, т.е. первая задача содержит стэк операций ActivityA -> ActivityС, а вторая задача содержит только ActivityB. Но согласно документации при нажатии на кнопку Назад из ActivityС должен быть возврат к предыдущей операции (ActivityB), однако на самом деле возврат происходит к ActivityA... Как это можно объяснить?

Comment: android какая версия на устройстве?

Comment: @TimurVI, обновила пост, добавила версии эмулятора и реального устройства

Comment: По варианту `standard` - клик по ярлыку обрабатывает лаунчер - свёрнутое приложение он просто разворачивает (так же, как recent apps), и флаги здесь не при чём. Но если Вы явно пошлёте интент на `ActivityA` - она будет создана в вызвавшем таске